# Does the $\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}$ hold?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In my book, it claimed $\binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + ... + \binom{9}{2} + \binom{10}{2} + \binom{11}{2} = \binom{12}{3}$.

I can't figure out How the author claimed the above true. Is there any method without just calculating?

Plus, From above I guess the $\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n+1}{2} = \binom{n+1}{3}$.
Then, Does $\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}$ hold in general?

Comment: Try $r=1$. Do you get equality in this case? $\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n+1}{2} = \binom{n+1}{3}$ is also false.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, It didn't occur to me to think the $r=1$ case. Yes. I got it. It is not true in general.

Comment: The sum is just [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)

Comment: Re the comment of @Sil, you can tell at a glance that the hockey stick identity is valid, without doing (much) Math, simply by using the Pascal's Triangle rule that each number is the sum of the 2 numbers above it.  When applying this rule against (for example) the Wikipedia diagram in the article cited by Sil's comment, simply put a **crook** into the top of the hockey stick, substituting $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{0} = 1~$ for $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{0} = 1.$